# wget retrieves content in HTML format other than the specified?

Tags: wget

I'm currently working on a small project where I'll gather information from a few different tools and generate a web report.

Right now I'm trying to export an image of one of my graphs on Check MK using PNP4Nagios but so far no success.

According to the documentation on PNP4NAGIOS - Data Export:

> You can also use wget to generate images and place them in periodic
> reports. One example may be:
>
> `wget -O image.png 'http://<user>:<pass>@<nagios-server>/pnp4nagios/image?host=<hostname>&srv=<service>&view=2&source=0'`

I used the same command with my URL: `wget -O image.png 'http://<my user>:<my pass>@<my Nagios server>/pnp4nagios/image?host=Test&srv=_HOST_&source=0&view=0'`

The command above would get me the image of the round trip average of host "Test" but regardless of what I do it returns an error 404.

I tried to add my Check MK's site name to the URL (`.../project_v1/localhost/pnp4nagios/...`) but it returned a HTML file, not an image.

I know wget is a command line utility used for downloading files from the Internet so the method itself may not be the error.

Currently working with Check MK 1.2.8p27 and PNP 0.6.25 on Ubuntu 16.04.

And in case I posted this question in the wrong section, I apologize and I'll delete and move it to the right place.

Comment: If you open `'http://<my user>:<my pass>@<my Nagios server>/pnp4nagios/image?host=Test&srv=_HOST_&source=0&view=0'` in lynx or some other browser, what do you get?

Comment: @muru If I open `http://<my user>:<my pass>@<my Nagios server>/pnp4nagios/image?host=Test&srv=_HOST_&source=0&view=0'` I get an error informing that "The requested URL /pnp4nagios/image was not found on this server". But if I add my site's name to the URL `http://<user>:<pass>@<Nagios Server>/<Site name>/pnp4nagios/image?host=Test&srv=_HOST_&source=0&view=0` I do get a HTML file. I can take a screenshot of my screen if you'd like.

Comment: So in neither case do you get an image file?

Comment: @muru Yes. Regardless of the URL I use, I can't get the image file. All I've done was to download and follow the usual configuration for Check MK, nothing else.